# Как правильно сделать Search компонент используя React

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент Posts.jsx который содержит в себе Search.jsx, проблема в том, что я не знаю как правильно сделать компонент Search - должен ли он быть функциональный или через класс. И как передавать значения с input при нажатии на кнопку search в Posts компонент.

Posts.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import { CardList } from '../../components/card-list/card-list.component';
import { Search } from '../../components/search/search.component';
import postApi from '../../services/postApi';

class PostsListPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            posts: [],
            search: '',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        postApi.getPosts().then(({ data }) => {
            this.setState({ posts: data.list });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { posts, search } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Search placeholder="Search post" />
                <CardList posts={posts} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PostsListPage;
```

Search.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export const Search = ({ placeholder, handleClick }) => (
    <div className="mb-3 d-flex">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="search" placeholder={placeholder} />
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Search
        </button>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `PostsListPage` значение input вы храните в this.state.search. Как решение, можно добавить в `PostsListPage` функцию, которая делает апдейт search:

```
updateSearch = (value) => {
  this.setState(() => {
    return {
      search: value
    };
  }
}
```

Передаете эту функцию в child-компонент:

```
<Search placeholder="Search post" updateSearch={this.updateSearch} />
```

В компоненте `Search` вы просто вызываете функцию родителя при каждом обновлении input (в параметрах передаете значение input):

```
props.updateSearch(value);
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как в компоненте search связать Input и отправку value с инпута в родительский компонент

Comment: @dimafront, на input вешаете событие onChange <input type="text" onChange={onChange} .../> . В компоненте Search описываете функцию onChange, в которой будете вызывать props.updateSearch(value);